# Split Iframe data into different variable

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have an iframe which I load a PHP script into. It displays multiple first and last names of users like `mike smith tom smith jim smith ron smith` etc. What I am trying to accomplish is to separate each set of names into variables using javascript. This is what I have come up with so far, but it captures all the names not sure how to split:

```
var iFrameBody1 = document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.document.body; 

name1 = iFrameBody1.textContent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Javascript method SPLIT to convert the names into an array you can iterate over.

**Example: Split a string into an array of substrings:**

```
<script>
var str = "mike smith tom smith jim smith ron smith";
var res = str.split(" ");
</script>
```

**The result of res will be an array with the values:**
    mike,smith,tom,smith,jim,smith,ron,smith

Example taken from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Something like that should do the trick!

Succes!